# Mongoose not returning HTTP status code 204 on delete

Tags: mongodb, rest, mongoose

I am using `mongoose` for `mongodb` and trying to delete a record. A standard REST API should return in a `204` response on delete. However mongoose is returning `200`

```
  return await ppc.deleteOne({ _id: id });
```

With response having `deletedCount`

```
data:
    deletedCount: 1
status: 200
```

or using

```
  return await ppc.findOneAndRemove({ _id: id});
```

returns same `200` with `body`. Is there any `delete` API which returns `204` by default?

Like in `spring boot` or `spring data rest` it returns `204` by default for a successful delete request. I understand if I need body in response I would need to send `200` for a proper REST API convention. However if I need to return the `204` myself with mongoose, mongo db I would need to check for deletedCount first ,which I can do either on backend or frontend which is a little extra work. I wanted to ensure is there some setting or some other API which defaults it to `204`?

Issue with `200` status code is that `mongoose` even return `200` for a `ID` which doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate the function of Mongodb as a database vs the HTTP response code your app returns, there is no relation between the two.

`200` is the default "success" response code as it's returned because your app successfully executes the code with no errors. `mongoose` or `mongodb` are not the ones returning the status.

What it sounds like you want to be doing is incorporate some basic logic into your routes, like so:

```
const delResult = await ppc.deleteOne({ _id: id });
response.json({statusCode: 402, ...delResult})
```

With `mongoose` you can also prebuild triggers to execute after certain operations to handle this type of custom logic for you, that's how you avoid code duplication throughout your app.